# EasyMock still goes into implementation of a method mocked with addMockedMethod

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I am trying to write a unit-test in Java. Due to the structure of Java class, I have to come up with a way in which whenever a constructor of a class is called, a mocked object of that class is created. I want to mock 2 methods of that class.

```
CallToBeMocked mockCallToBeMocked = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(CallToBeMocked.class)
                .withConstructor(ArgumentA.class, ArgumentB.class, ArgumentC.class)
                .withArgs(mockArgumentA, mockArgumentB, mockArgumentC)
                .addMockedMethod("isProxied", ArgumentA.class)
                .addMockedMethod("remoteCall", String.class, ArgumentA.class, Object.class)
                .createMock();

 EasyMock.expect(mockCallToBeMocked.isProxied(mockArgumentA)).andReturn(false);
 EasyMock.expect(mockCallToBeMocked.remoteCall("ip-address", mockArgumentA, null)).andThrow(new Exception()).times(3);
```

The problem is that although I have clearly specified that `isProxied` and `remoteCall` methods have to be mocked and I have given appropriate expectations for those methods, it still starts going into the actual implementations of these methods.

Comment: Please let me know if any other detail is required.

Comment: Are the methods final?

Comment: No, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

It should perfectly work. So something else is going on. Here is a working example based on your code. What's different from your actual implementation?

```
public class PartialTest {

    public interface ArgumentA { }
    public interface ArgumentB { }
    public interface ArgumentC { }

    public static class CallToBeMocked {
        public CallToBeMocked(ArgumentA a, ArgumentB b, ArgumentC c) {

        }

        public boolean isProxied(ArgumentA a) {
            return true;
        }

        public int remoteCall(String ip, ArgumentA a, Object any) throws Exception {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        ArgumentA mockArgumentA = createNiceMock(ArgumentA.class);
        ArgumentB mockArgumentB = createNiceMock(ArgumentB.class);
        ArgumentC mockArgumentC = createNiceMock(ArgumentC.class);

        CallToBeMocked mockCallToBeMocked = createMockBuilder(CallToBeMocked.class)
                .withConstructor(ArgumentA.class, ArgumentB.class, ArgumentC.class)
                .withArgs(mockArgumentA, mockArgumentB, mockArgumentC)
                .addMockedMethod("isProxied", ArgumentA.class)
                .addMockedMethod("remoteCall", String.class, ArgumentA.class, Object.class)
                .createMock();

        expect(mockCallToBeMocked.isProxied(mockArgumentA)).andReturn(false);
        expect(mockCallToBeMocked.remoteCall("ip-address", mockArgumentA, null)).andThrow(new Exception()).times(3);

        replay(mockCallToBeMocked);

        assertFalse(mockCallToBeMocked.isProxied(mockArgumentA));
        try {
            mockCallToBeMocked.remoteCall("ip-address", mockArgumentA, null);
            fail("Should throw");
        } catch (Exception e) { }
        try {
            mockCallToBeMocked.remoteCall("ip-address", mockArgumentA, null);
            fail("Should throw");
        } catch (Exception e) { }
        try {
            mockCallToBeMocked.remoteCall("ip-address", mockArgumentA, null);
            fail("Should throw");
        } catch (Exception e) { }

        verify(mockCallToBeMocked);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If we aren't tied to EasyMock, here's a way in which the same functionality can be achieved using Mockito.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.mockito.Mockito;

....

ClassToBeMocked myMock = Mockito.mock(ClassToBeMocked.class);

Mockito
    .when(myMock.isProxied(any(ArgumentA.class)))
    .thenReturn(false);

Mockito
    .when(myMock.remoteCall(any(String.class), any(ArgumentA.class), any(Object.class)))
    .thenThrow(new Exception("monkeys"));

<USE ``myMock``>

verify(myMock, times(1)).isProxied(mockArgumentA);
verify(myMock, times(3)).remoteCall("ip-address", mockArgumentA, null);
```